# custom AuthorizeAttribute + custom SiteMapProvider related?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, authorization, sitemap, authorize-attribute

I have a custom `SiteMapProvider` (populated from database) and a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` (validates current users roles + requested page against Role_Page database) for controller classes.

I have to implement the function `SiteMapProvider.IsAccessibleToUser(context, node)`. I also have to implement `AuthorizeAttribute.AuthorizeCore(context)`.

**How are these two functions related? Isn't there some way to '*attribute*' the SiteMapProvider?**

Some code:

---

**edit:** ***Might this be a solution (inside `AuthorizeCore()`)?*** *`context` however is `HttpContextBase`, and `IsAccessibleToUser()` only takes `HttpContext` as parameter.*

```
If Not SiteMap.Provider.IsAccessibleToUser(context, SiteMap.CurrentNode) Then
```

---

**current code:**

```
Public Class CustomValidateAuthorization : Inherits AuthorizeAttribute
    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Function AuthorizeCore(ByVal httpContext As System.Web.HttpContextBase) As Boolean
        If Not Global.Page.IsAccessibleToUser(httpContext.User) Then
            //Exception or redirect (in exception)?
            // or return false?
        End If

        Return True
    End Function
End Class

Public Class CustomSiteMapProvider : Inherits StaticSiteMapProvider
Public Overrides Function IsAccessibleToUser(ByVal context As System.Web.HttpContext, ByVal node As System.Web.SiteMapNode) As Boolean
    Dim p As New BLL.Page
    p.LoadFromSiteMapNode(node)

    Return p.IsAccessibleToUser(context.User)
End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I currently use the default sitemapprovider twice.